# Credentials not showing in jenkins dashboard

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, dockerhub

I need to add my docker hub credentials into jenkins but credentials task is not showing in jenkins dashboard.

I have downloaded credentials plugin but also im not getting credentials task.

[image]

Please Help me on this

Comment: You can find it inside Manage Jenkins >> Manage Credentials

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credentials inside `Manage Jenkins` >> `Manage Credentials` are stored in global scope - it means what they are accessible for every project in jenkins. If only you using jenkins than it's ok. To make jenkins show you credentials just update credentials plugin to the latest version.

Also it's a good practise to create credentials in your project's folder.

Answer (score -1):

Jenkins 2.346.3

Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins > Click on available > enter credentials.